# a red-beard man (or) a red-bearded man

Tags: adjectives

would you please help me about this? which is correct: **a red-beard man** or

**a red-bearded man**?

Thanks alot

Comment: Better, "a **red-bearded** man" / "a man in a **red beard**", but  "a red-bearded man" is not incorrect.

Comment: Both could be correct, depending on context. Aside from the answer given, "a red-beard man" might be a man who likes red beards . . .

Comment: Not "a man in a beard" - "a man with a beard".

Answer (score 1):

'A red-bearded man' is correct. 'Red-bearded' is a participle acting like an adjective, even though it has the -ed ending like a verb.

Also, there is no such word as 'alot'. It is two words 'a lot'.

Answer (score -1):

if the choice is **a red-**beard** man** (or) a red-**bearded** man, consider [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/160163?redirectedFrom=red%20bearded#eid) guidance for this adjective:

1. Of a man: having a red beard.

As in:

> 2003   Columbia Journalism Rev. Sept.–Oct. 27/1   The question comes
>   from Nandor, a **red-bearded** trollish **man** moderating an evening
>   meeting.

and

1985   R. Curtis & B. Elton Blackadder II in R. Curtis et al. Black-Adder (1998) 161/1 (stage direct.)    A dark and rummy place, where sits Redbeard Rum, a huge **** pirate.